# How do we minimize $\left(x+a+b\right)\left(x+a-b\right)\left(x-a+b\right)\left(x-a-b\right)$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

Find the minimum value of the following function, where a and b are real
numbers.
\begin{align} f(x)&=\left(x+a+b\right)\left(x+a-b\right)\left(x-a+b\right)\left(x-a-b\right) \end{align}
Note: The solution should not contain any calculus methods.

So I conjugated the parenthesizes two by two, and I got:
\begin{align} f(x)&=\left(x^2-(a+b)^2\right)\left(x^2-(a-b)^2\right) \end{align}
Can somebody help me to take this problem further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your work
$$f(x)=x^4-2(a^2+b^2)x^2+(a^2-b^2)^2$$ or
$$f(x)=(x^2-a^2-b^2)^2-(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2$$ or
$$f(x)=(x^2-a^2-b^2)^2-4a^2b^2.$$
Now, we see that
$$f(x)\geq-4a^2b^2$$ and the equality occurs for $x^2=a^2+b^2$, which is possible.

Thus, $$\min_{\mathbb R}f=-4a^2b^2.$$
Done!

Comment: Could you please explain that how did you get the third function?

Comment: @Nariman Zendehrooh $-(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2=-a^4-2a^2b^2-b^4+a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4=-4a^2b^2$.

Comment: Great! I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(y-2c)(y-2d)=(y-(c+d))^2+4cd-(c+d)^2\ge?$$

Comment: Nice approach!.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to apply it. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: @NarimanZendehrooh, Now for real $y-(c+d),$  $$(y-(c+d))^2\ge0$$  Can you recognize $y=x^2,2c=(a+b)^2,2d=?$

Answer (score 1):

*Just another solution in the same spirit as lab bhattacharjee's answer.*

$$ f(x)=\left(x+a+b\right)\left(x+a-b\right)\left(x-a+b\right)\left(x-a-b\right) $$
$$f(x)=x^4-2\left( a^2+1\right) x^2+(a^2-1)^2$$ Complete the square
$$f(x)=\left(x^2-(a^2+1)\right)^2-(a^2+1)^2+(a^2-1)^2=\left(x^2-(a^2+1)\right)^2-4a^2$$